# Accordion display full content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

My problem is that my accordion shows a scrollbar in every content section. 
So I decided to set overflow:hidden:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {  
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
    border-top: 0;

    overflow: hidden;
```

Scroll-bar is gone. That's what I want. 
Now the problem is that I cannot see the text that is way down there since there is no scroll-bar. 
Is there a way to make the accordion content space automatically detect how much space is needed for different text lengths. Right now I feel like having a fixed spaced. If there is little text, there is a huge margin to the bottom. If there is too much text, only the part will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the code:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
        heightStyle:"content"
    });

add heightStyle:"content"
```

Comment: Wow ! Works like a charm ! thanks man, love you bro ;) my mistake was that i was looking at the css file. never thought of the html file. thanks again. have a nice day !